# Good resource for nonlinear and linear programming

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research

What is a good book to learn nonlinear/linear programming. I am looking for a book with a clear style and motivating examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jiri Matousek, Bernd Gärtner. *Understanding and Using Linear Programming*, 2007.

David G. Luenberger, Yinyu Ye. *Linear and Nonlinear Programming*, 3rd Edition, 2008.

Mokhtar S. Bazaraa, Hanif D. Sherali, C. M. Shetty. *Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms*, 3rd Edition, 2006.