# Reference book for these types of problems

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

From time to time I come across problems similar to (min, max, max min, etc)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{j,i} \quad & (j-i)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & i \le j\\
  & n \ge i,j \ge 0    \\
  & \textrm{some nonlinear/combinatorial conditions}    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and I know I can change it to

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{j} \quad  (j- &\max_{i} i)\\
  & \textrm{s.t.} \quad   n \ge j \ge i \ge 0    \\
  & \textrm{some nonlinear/combinatorial conditions}    \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and come up with an algorithm to solve it by iterating over j. Can you please tell me if there is a book in which these rules of separation, associative/commutative/etc, conversion of min to max or max to min, and more general principles  are taught?

Comment: It looks like you're discussing optimization problems such as integer programming? I don't have a reference recommendation though.

Comment: The 2 formulations are not Same. We may not get the Solution for formulation-1 with formulation-2. Eg : In F1 we may have $MIN(J-I)=3$ with $(I,J)=(2,5)$ & In F2 we may have $MAX(I)=4$ with $(I,J)=(4,9)$ hence $MIN(J-MAX(I))=5$ : Solutions are not Same !!

Comment: @prem I edited my question. Hopefully this version is correct given i must satisfy the other conditions as well. What I meant by F2 is that I calculate that function for each fixed j, and then take the maximum of them.

Comment: That is still not Equivalent. I could Explain why , in More Detail , but that will require the Answer Box. You are asking about book recommendations & hence the answers should talk about that. I am unable to Post some "answer" to explain why the formulations are not Equivalent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Linear Programming books cover topics like model conversion like you mentioned, though they tend to be sub-topics of often larger problems. If you’re looking to get into Linear and Non-Linear Programming (since you mentioned Non-Linear and combinatorial constraints):

- “[Non-Linear Programming: Theory and Algorithms, 3rd Edition](https://books.google.com/books/about/Nonlinear_Programming.html?id=fGpRAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description)” by Mokhtar S. Bazaraa
- [Hyper comprehensive book list of Linear/Integer/etc.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20643/1119495)
- [A couple Non-Linear and Linear book references](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225101/1119495) and [some others](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89618/1119495)

If you want general practice problems:

- [Problems in OR and e.t.c.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553246/1119495)
- The [practice problems that appear dynamically](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear%20programming%20practice%20problems&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari) by Google